# PDO Class not working even

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I followed this tutorial here: http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/ and wrote the following class.

**database.class.php**

```
<?php

require_once './dbconfig.inc.php';

/**
 * MySQL Database PDO Wrapper Class.
 */
class Database {

    private $db_host = DB_HOST;
    private $db_user = DB_USER;
    private $db_name = DB_NAME;
    private $db_pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->db_host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name;
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'//careful with this one, though
        );

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $this->error = $ex->getMessage();
            echo $this->error;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute() {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function getRows() {
        $this->execute();
        $this->stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    public function getRow() {
        $this->execute();
        $this->stmt->fetch();
    }

    public function rowCount() {
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

}
```

**dbconfig.inc.php**

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'hms');
define('DB_PASS', 'root');
```

**demo.php**

```
<?php

require_once './database.class.php';

$db = new Database();

$db->query('SELECT * FROM appointment');

$result = $db->getRows();
print_r($result);
```

The connection is successful but demo.php doesn't show anything. On chrome it returns a 500 Internal Server Error. I am running my scripts in LAMP stack on CentOS. My DB Server is MariaDB 5.5

Any feedback on why its not working is very much appreciated.

Comment: What's the error in your apache log?

Comment: in demo.php add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` and check

Comment: `getRow` and `getRows` need `return` statements, but I don't think that should cause this problem.

Comment: Plus, `require_once './database.class.php';` yet you claim your file is `dbclass.inc.php` - I'd call that a "file not found".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry for the confusion. I corrected it in the main post. But I have cross checked and the file names are fine.

Comment: @Barmar after I checked the error_log I found this `[Tue Jun 28 00:28:41.074847 2016] [:error] [pid 4444] [client ::1:46337] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/PhpUtils/database.class.php on line 35
` Is it because I am using select all query?

Comment: check last update in my Answer

Comment: Instead of catching specifically PDOException, try catching all exceptions to see if there is an underlying systemic issue that is being rethrown by the PDO driver.

Comment: Not really sure where the purpose for the class is, as you are really not adding any value to the underlying PDO class, and are in fact significantly obfuscating the underlying implementation. For example why call method `query()` when within the class it is under performing a statement preparation? Meanwhile you do not save the calling class from having to work with PDO and its related class.  For example, it seems clear that the caller would need to prepare a statement, bind variables to it, and then iterate through result sets.  Why shouldn't they just do that with underlying PDO objects?

Comment: @MikeBrant I think I am gonna take your advice and drop this idea of a PDO wrapper. I am clueless why its happening though.

Comment: This tutorial is written by someone who has no clue, it contains [almost every possible mistake](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes).

Answer (score 1):

@Philipp is right. you should `return` from functions.

So in case provided you definitely need to:

```
public function getRows() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Check @Fred-ii- comment: *require_once './database.class.php'; yet you claim your file is **dbclass.inc.php** - I'd call that a "file not found".*

**UPDATE** Change here:

```
 public function getError() {
    return $this->error ;
 }
 public function __construct() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->db_host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name;
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'//careful with this one, though
    );

    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $options);
        $this->error = 'ok';
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $this->error = $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and in `demo.php` change to:

```
$db = new Database()
if (($err = $db->getError())=='ok') {
  ...
} else {
  echo $err;
}
```

Comment: an answer was deleted with the same thing

Comment: @Fred-ii- there could be php and/or apache settings to return 500 on any php error or warning

Comment: I edited like he mentioned. I realised it was a foolish error. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: I've my money on [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061002/pdo-class-not-working-even#comment63560991_38061002) I left the guy, but nothing from it. So.. OP's left, no idea. Edit: ah, there he is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh, I see :-)

Comment: @Psycho_Coder you have a few comments up there about checking for logs and error reporting. If you have access to logs, look at them and tell us what you see. If not, then use error reporting to catch and display possible errors. A 500 is a server error.

Comment: I added `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` to demo.php but it doesn't show anything. On chrome it still returns HTTP 500. I will check logs now.

Comment: so try to echo something and comment all the rest. if you see your echo. then uncomment line by line and echo line number after each line of code :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-
I checked access_log under ./var/log/httpd and it shows `::1 - - [28/Jun/2016:00:17:54 +0530] "GET /PhpUtils/demo.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"` Do you want me to check something else?

Comment: @Alex I made the change and still the same. Also checked logs but it shows the same error

Comment: `[Tue Jun 28 00:28:41.074847 2016] [:error] [pid 4444] [client ::1:46337] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/PhpUtils/database.class.php on line 35 `

Comment: I updated the code like you said bu no improvement. I cross checked by running another dynamic web app to check if mysql is working or not but its running well. The error is occurring when I am using PDO in a class. I tried it without the Database class and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @Psycho_Coder ... without wanting to dwell into dogma, i think the 'gawds' of coding are trying to whisper something about the value of wrapping PDO :)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg yeah I think so too. For now I am gonna drop this idea.